# Unable to connect with mongodb from internal kubernetes cluster

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-aks

I tried setting up mongodb via bitnami stable/mongodb helm chart, the helm chart installation command is as follows -

```
helm install --name mongo --set mongodbRootPassword=mongo,mongodbUsername=mongo,mongodbPassword=mongo,mongodbDatabase=database stable/mongodb
```

after creation of it, I am looking to connect my applications by following format of connection string

```
mongodb://[user]:[password]@[service].[namespace].svc.cluster.local:27017/[db]?replicaSet=rs0&authSource=admin
```

But I am getting error for this -

> failed to connect to server
>   [**mongo.shift-resourcing.svc.cluster.local:27017**] on first connect
>   [**MongoNetworkError: Client network socket disconnected before secure
>   TLS connection was established**]

The mongod.conf file is as follows -

```
# where and how to store data.
   storage:
      dbPath: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db
      journal:
       enabled: true
      directoryPerDB: false
    # where to write logging data.
    systemLog:
      destination: file
      quiet: false
      logAppend: true
      logRotate: reopen
      path: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/logs/mongodb.log
      verbosity: 0
     # network interfaces
    net:
      port: 27017
      unixDomainSocket:
        enabled: true
        pathPrefix: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp
      ipv6: false
      bindIpAll: true
    # replica set options
    #replication:
      #replSetName: replicaset
      #enableMajorityReadConcern: true
    # process management options
    processManagement:
       fork: false
       pidFilePath: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb.pid
    # set parameter options
    setParameter:
       enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
    # security options
    security:
      authorization: enabled
      #keyFile: replace_me
```

Comment: It seems to me you setup your mongod instance to use TLS.  If this is the case then mongo expects bi-directional TLS meaning both the server and the client must present certificates and the certificates must be valid in the chain of authority.  Please provide the mongod.conf file found in your K8s container.  This will help provide guidance into your connectivity issue.  You may want to test without TLS first then add it back in once you determined your ingress is working correctly.

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.tls for TLS connection string options...

Comment: @tushar-mahajan did you manage to solve this issue?